# How is this image effect created?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have looked at this page for some time now. Amazing, really. But I can't tell how the background image effect that happens on scroll works. Have gone through the code found that they are using Jquery plus a number of scrolling plugins, but nothing about the images that I can see.

How would you say that it's done?

The site: http://herohousing.org/UBBT/

Comment: Very interesting indeed, this is a page that will take some time to disect... but very cool.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? For a lot of things no javascript is needed at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This trick is quite simple and just needs some CSS where each panel has a background image that is fixed:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png);
        background-attachment: fixed;
        border: thin solid;
    }
    div.a {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-color: #FDD;
    }
    div.b {
        background-repeat: repeat-y;
        background-color: #DFD;
    }
    div.c {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-color: #DDF;
    }
</style>

<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="c">C</div>
```

Here I’m using the same background image but the different background color and image repeat should show you that it’s three different elements.

---

**Edit**    Ok, it seem’s that some doubt what I am writing. And in fact, the quoted site uses jQuery for this. But only to fit the image to the width and height of the browser’s viewport since you cannot size a background image yet. CSS 3 specifies a [`background-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) but its support is still proprietary using the vendor specific prefix like `-khtml-` (Konqueror), `-moz-` (Gecko based browsers like Firefox), `-o-` (Opera) and `-webkit-` (WebKit based browsers like Safari).

If you can abstain from that, you can use the CSS technique I showed you.

Comment: You've forgot to use JQuery to assign images on `.a`, `.b` and `.c` div's.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: Why should I use jQuery when there is a simple CSS solution? And the DIVs *do* have a background image.

Comment: But still they do something with JS. If I disable JS then no background image is shown at all.

Comment: @Felix: This is done with pure CSS. There is no need for jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: @Felix, don't over-complicate. Gumbo's technique works for almost everyone, regardless of JavaScript. This is a *bonus.*

Comment: @ricebowl, @Gumbo: I don't want to over-complicate. The less JS one has to use the better. I just wanted to point out that the particular website the OP mentions uses JS to show the images.

Comment: @ Gumbo. Thanks for your help with this! Great stuff!

Comment: @ Gumbo. Appreciate your edit. This cleared up the situation even more! Thanks again!

Comment: Then how does scrolling images work with just pure CSS? clearly, there's a JS to calculate scrolling and changing image position.

Answer (score 2):

It's 4 divs with a different background image for each, what makes the effect work particularly well is the "background-attached: fixed;" property to stop the background scrolling.

If you download Firebug for Firefox, you can inspect the div's and observe how the CSS makes the page behave and attempt to replicate it for yourself.

Really nice looking effect I must admit :-)